# Azure application gateway - create path based rule to homepage

Tags: azure, azure-application-gateway

I need to create a path based rule that would redirect homepage to another backend pool than default one, but I can't find a workaround to do so. In other words, my homepage doesn't belong to the default backend, and I need to find a way to route the requests (only for homepage) to another backend

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I could not find a way to redirect the homepage to a different backend pool. By default, all requests that are not directed to another pool. are sent to the default backend pool.

What I would do is make the homepage pool the default pool, and then direct all other requests to the other pool(s) as needed.

Comment: I know that this would be a solution, but as I explained this is not what I need to do

Comment: Hi @GregOs Did you manage to get a solution for this? I am faced with the same issue. It is not feasible to map routes of all other pages in the site and so I need to route '/'